# Entry creation returns a 201 but accessing it returns 404

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have a simple **Spring Data Rest** implementation of user creation using **Hibernate** and **MongoDB**.

**User.java**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class User {

    private @Id String username;

    private String about;
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@CrossOrigin(methods = {GET, PUT, POST})
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    <S extends User> S save(S s);
}
```

Then I make a POST call to `/users` with this body:

```
{
    "username": "username1",
    "about": "example"
}
```

I get a `201 Created` response with the following body:

```
{
    "about": "example",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/username1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/username1"
        }
    }
}
```

I make a `GET` request to `/users` to see if the user was indeed added and this response is returned rightfully so:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "users": [
            {
                "about": "example",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/username1"
                    },
                    "user": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users/username1"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/users{?page,size,sort}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "profile": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/profile/users"
        }
    },
    "page": {
        "size": 20,
        "totalElements": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "number": 0
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

But then I access the URL of the user provided in the links, i.e., `http://localhost:8080/api/users/username1` but I get a `404 Not Found` response.

What am I doing wrong? I've tried looking through examples and documentation but nothing seems to do the work. If I add the `@AutoGenerated` annotation it works, but I obviously want the `id` to be provided by the request as the `username`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `User.java`, I changed the declaration of `username` to this:

```
@Id
@JsonProperty("username")
@NotBlank
private String id;
```

MongoDb requires `_id` as the primary key for every document by default otherwise it won't get indexed. I had to change the field name to id so that it translates to `_id` on MongoDB with the `@Id` annotation. To fix this on the consumer side, I used `@JsonProperty("username")` to get the value from the `username` property of the request's JSON body.